# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "freegeoip.io" does not match the server certificate in ruby geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, geocoder

I am using `gem 'geocoder'` issue with this gem

My Gemfile.lock

```
geocoder (1.4.4)
```

Getting the below error:-

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 485ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname "freegeoip.io" does not match the server certificate):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freegeoip moved servers from http://freegeoip.io to http://freegeoip.net...
Updating the gem to `gem geocoder '~> 1.4.5` fixed this for me.